# Spring: html form instead of spring form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If I want to pass two parameters from a jsp page to a method of a controller,without to bind a bean, can I use a simple html form? or I have to use a spring form?.Sorry for my english.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. The simplest solution for your use case is probably retrieving the two submitted parameters using `@RequestParam` annotation as shown below:

```
<form method="get" action="/controllerMapping">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and in your controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/controllerMapping")
public String foo(@RequestParam("foo") String foo,
                  @RequestParam("bar") String bar) {
    System.out.println("Value of form element 'foo' = " + foo);
    System.out.println("Value of form element 'bar' = " + bar);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The spring `<form:form>` tag is just a JSTL tag library that creates a regular HTML form for you, so yes, you can use a regular HTML form.

However in general, I would recommend using Spring's form tag library to take advantage of HTML escaping and CSRF protection with Spring Security.